# Routing HTTP verbs in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm trying to route *only* an http verb. Say I have a comments resource like so:

```
map.resources :comments
```

And would like to be able to destroy all comments by sending a `DELETE /comments` request. I.e. I want to be able to map just the http verb without the "action name" part of the route. Is this possible?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
map.resources :comments, :only => :destroy
```

which produces a route like the following (you can verify with `rake routes`)

```
DELETE /comments/:id(.:format) {:controller=>"comments", :action=>"destroy"}
```

But note that the RESTful destroy is designed for removing a **specific** record not **all** records so this route is still expecting an :id parameter. A hack might be to pass some sentinel value for :id representing "all" in your application context.

On the other hand, if your comments belong to another model, then removing the other model would/should remove the comments too. This is conventionally how multiple row deletes might normally occur.

Comment: The comments resource in this case was just fictional^^ There really should be a way to do this, just as the default 'remove' route does...

Answer (score 1):

Since this is not standard RESTful action, you will need to use a custom route.

```
map.connect '/comments', 
  :controller => 'comments',
  :action => "destroy_all",
  :conditions => { :method => :delete }
```

In your controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  # your RESTful actions here

  def destroy_all
    # destroy all your comments here
  end
end
```

In view, invoke like this:

```
<%= link_to "delete all comments", 
        comments_path,
        :method => :delete, 
        :confirm => "Are you sure" %>
```

ps. I didn't test this code, but I think it should work.

Comment: wouldn't this action better be added with just a

    map.resources :comments, :collection => { :destroy_all => :delete }

I get the feeling that just DELETE'ing to the collection resource would be more `RESTful`...
Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Using the :collection attribute will generate the URL as /messages/delete_all and according the question is not desirable.